# How to SSH into VM running within Parallels on OSX while connected via Junos Pulse VPN?

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, parallels, juniper

I am working with OS X 10.9 and Parallels Desktop 9. Within Parallels I run a Linux VM using a Shared Network setting.

If I am on my company network I able to SSH into the VM from my OS X terminal (via IP 10.211.55.3).

However, if I connect via VPN (Juniper Networks Junos Pulse) this does not work anymore. Somehow I need to tell OS X that it should not route IP 10.211.55.3 through the VPN.

Any idea how to do this? Is this really the problem?

Comment: i'm not that familiar with much of what you speak of, only a little bit with ssh, but ssh -v might give some clue sometimes as to what is stopping it getting in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

Go to menu Parallels > Preferences > Network > Shared

Add a port forwarding rule such as:

- TCP
- Source 2200
- Forward to (dropdown): YourMV
- Destination port 22

Connect to machine via `ssh localhost -p 2200` !